# Django Field defines a relation with model , which is either not installed, or is abstract

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My code is as shown below:

```
class X(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'X'

    ph_no = models.CharField(max_length =255,null=False)

    y = models.ForeignKey('y',on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class M(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'M'

    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255,null= False)

    x = models.ForeignKey('X',on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class y (models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'y'

    details =  models.TextField(null= False)
```

Now when , with this schema, I run the migrations, I get the following error

```
appName.M.x: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'X', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
appName.M.x: (fields.E307) The field appName.M.x was declared with a lazy reference to 'appName.X', but app 'appName' doesn't provide model 'X'.
```

My settings.py file is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'dashboard'
]
```

Comment: Are you sure you did not wrote *lowercase* `'x'` in your `ForeignKey`? The names are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, I have written uppercase 'X' in the code

Comment: What if you use `X` instead of `'X'` and perform an import? Did you register the application where `X` is defined in the `settings.py`?

Comment: I agree with that. The error clearly says `'appName' doesn't provide model 'X'`

Comment: Can you share your declaration of model `'y'`?

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto I have updated the definition for `y` in the question

Comment: Well, it works in my computer as you shared it. Did you check what @WillemVanOnsem asked about checking the `settings.py`? Can you share the `INSTALLED_APPS` entry of your `setting.py`?

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto I have shared the `settings.py` in my updated question

Answer (score 0):

in installed app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',

*'dashboard'*

with 
'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig'
]
```

and apps.py in dashboard application

```
   from django.apps import AppConfig
```

class DashboardConfig(AppConfig):
       name = 'dashboard'